# Issues with Http testing (MockBackend, MockConnection) after Angular2 update in Karma

Tags: angular

After updating Angular2 to newest version (alpha 53), I encountered a problem with imports of files in Karma related to testing Http services. I have references like this in Karma:

```
files: [
    {pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js', included: true, watched: true},
    {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js', included: true, watched: true},
    {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.js', included: true, watched: true},
    {pattern: 'node_modules/  angular2/bundles/http.js', included: true, watched: true},
    {pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true}]
```

I know that MockBackend, MockConnection moved from angular2/http to angular2/http/testing, my problem is that I don't know how to import these moved classes, as I didn't find anything in bundles folder (or whole angular2 directory for that matter) that resembles http-testing.js or something similar, and I was unable to find it in any bundle file that is present.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already know where those classes are and you don't know where to import them from? Importing them from [`angular2/http/testing`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/backends/mock_backend.ts#L102) should be enough.

Comment: Yes IDE can recognize them and compile them, however when Karma needs to get a concrete files which are used to load all angular dependencies. All needed classes are in bundles folder, however newly moved http/testing classes aren't available in bundles folder...

Comment: I see, have you tried importing them directly from their path? Like in this [file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/http/testing.ts#L1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of beta 0 MockBackend/Connection are part of testing.dev.js bundle.